# Why my loop doesn't work? My loop in submodule file doesn't run

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've been working on my thesis today. I has several file to run this for one training iteration. It run well when I run it separated, or one by one manually. But, some iteration and all the inner loop only run once, since I changed the code to be callable function from main function. Here is the main Function

```
from count_class_word import count_class_word
from count_word_occurences import count_word_occurences
from count_probs import count_probs
from testing_naivebayes import test_naive_bayes

if __name__ == '__main__':
    step_constant = 694
    initial = 1
    start = 1
    end = 5
    while(initial <= 1):
        # count_class_word(start, end)
        count_word = count_word_occurences(start, end)
        # count_probs()
        # test_naive_bayes(start, end)
        start += step_constant
        end += step_constant
        initial += 1
    print "\n\nDONE"
```

Then this is the module file that failed to run it's loop

```
from mysql.connector import MySQLConnection, Error
from python_mysql_dbconfig import read_db_config
from progress.spinner import PieSpinner

def count_word_occurences(start, end):
    try:
        dbconfig = read_db_config()
        conn = MySQLConnection(**dbconfig)
        cursor = conn.cursor(buffered=True)
        cursor.execute("TRUNCATE dictionary")
        classes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
        for target in classes:
            if start == 1:
                cursor.execute("SELECT class, sentence FROM data3 WHERE class=%(target)s and id > %(id_target)s", {'target': target, 'id_target': end})
            elif end == 7433:
                cursor.execute("SELECT class, sentence FROM data3 WHERE class=%(target)s and id < %(id_target)s", {'target': target, 'id_target': start})
            else:              
                cursor.execute("SELECT class, sentence FROM data3 WHERE class=%(target)s and (id < %(id_start)s or id > %(id_end)s)", {'target': target,\
                 'id_start': start, 'id_end': end})
            class_documents = cursor.fetchall()
            print len(class_documents)
            for row in class_documents:
                print row[0]
                check = False
                sentence = row[1].split(' ')
                print len(sentence)
                for word in sentence:
                    print "lala"
                    # spinner.next()
                    if len(word) > 0:
                        if row[0] == 1:
                            cursor.execute("SELECT word, joy_occurences from dictionary WHERE word=%(target)s", {'target':word})
                        elif row[0] == 2:
                            cursor.execute("SELECT word, fear_occurences from dictionary WHERE word=%(target)s", {'target':word})
                        elif row[0] == 3:
                            cursor.execute("SELECT word, anger_occurences from dictionary WHERE word=%(target)s", {'target':word})
                        elif row[0] == 4:
                            cursor.execute("SELECT word, sadness_occurences from dictionary WHERE word=%(target)s", {'target':word})
                        elif row[0] == 5:
                            cursor.execute("SELECT word, disgust_occurences from dictionary WHERE word=%(target)s", {'target':word})
                        elif row[0] == 6:
                            cursor.execute("SELECT word, shame_occurences from dictionary WHERE word=%(target)s", {'target':word})
                        elif row[0] == 7:
                            cursor.execute("SELECT word, guilt_occurences from dictionary WHERE word=%(target)s", {'target':word})

                        check_word = cursor.fetchone()
                        if len(check_word) >= 1:
                            result = check_word[1] + 1
                            if row[0] == 1:
                                cursor.execute("UPDATE dictionary SET joy_occurences=%(number)s WHERE word=%(target)s", {'number':result, 'target':word})
                                # cursor.execute("SELECT word, joy_occurences from dictionary WHERE word=%(target)s", {'target':word})
                            elif row[0] == 2:
                                cursor.execute("UPDATE dictionary SET fear_occurences=%(number)s WHERE word=%(target)s", {'number':result, 'target':word})

                                # cursor.execute("SELECT word, fear_occurences from dictionary WHERE word=%(target)s", {'target':word})
                            elif row[0] == 3:
                                cursor.execute("UPDATE dictionary SET anger_occurences=%(number)s WHERE word=%(target)s", {'number':result, 'target':word})
                                # cursor.execute("SELECT word, anger_occurences from dictionary WHERE word=%(target)s", {'target':word})
                            elif row[0] == 4:
                                cursor.execute("UPDATE dictionary SET sadness_occurences=%(number)s WHERE word=%(target)s", {'number':result, 'target':word})
                                # cursor.execute("SELECT word, sadness_occurences from dictionary WHERE word=%(target)s", {'target':word})
                            elif row[0] == 5:
                                cursor.execute("UPDATE dictionary SET disgust_occurences=%(number)s WHERE word=%(target)s", {'number':result, 'target':word})
                                # cursor.execute("SELECT word, disgust_occurences from dictionary WHERE word=%(target)s", {'target':word})
                            elif row[0] == 6:
                                cursor.execute("UPDATE dictionary SET shame_occurences=%(number)s WHERE word=%(target)s", {'number':result, 'target':word})
                                # cursor.execute("SELECT word, shame_occurences from dictionary WHERE word=%(target)s", {'target':word})
                            elif row[0] == 7:
                                cursor.execute("UPDATE dictionary SET guilt_occurences=%(number)s WHERE word=%(target)s", {'number':result, 'target':word})
                                # cursor.execute("SELECT word, guilt_occurences from dictionary WHERE word=%(target)s", {'target':word})
                        else:
                            if row[0] == 1:
                                print "inserting"
                                cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dictionary(word, joy_occurences) VALUES(%(target)s, 1)", {'target':word})
                            elif row[0] == 2:
                                cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dictionary(word, fear_occurences) VALUES(%(target)s, 1)", {'target':word})
                            elif row[0] == 3:
                                cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dictionary(word, anger_occurences) VALUES(%(target)s, 1)", {'target':word})                            
                            elif row[0] == 4:
                                cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dictionary(word, sadness_occurences) VALUES(%(target)s, 1)", {'target':word})
                            elif row[0] == 5:
                                cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dictionary(word, disgust_occurences) VALUES(%(target)s, 1)", {'target':word})
                            elif row[0] == 6:
                                cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dictionary(word, shame_occurences) VALUES(%(target)s, 1)", {'target':word})
                            elif row[0] == 7:
                                cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dictionary(word, guilt_occurences) VALUES(%(target)s, 1)", {'target':word})
    except Error as e:
        print(e)

    finally:
        conn.commit()
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
        # spinner.finish()
        return 1
```

EDIT: It is supposed to run for 6 times as in "classes" array has.

Please any kind of help would be appreciated. I've try print the output but, it only show once. Here is the output

[image: Result from terminal]

Comment: How many times is it supposed to run?

Comment: It is supposed to run for 6 times as in "classes" array has.

Comment: You're talking about the `for target in classes` loop? We thought the problem was the `while initial <= 1:` loop.

Comment: The only guess I have is that an exception is breaking out of the loop, but your `except` statement should print out the error message.

Comment: Yeah @Barmar, it is in "classes" loop, that's why i'm wondering why

Comment: FYI, your `SELECT + UPDATE-or-INSERT` can probably be combined into a single `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`. But this probably isn't related to the looping problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
from count_class_word import count_class_word
from count_word_occurences import count_word_occurences
from count_probs import count_probs
from testing_naivebayes import test_naive_bayes

if __name__ == '__main__':
    step_constant = 694
    initial = 1
    start = 1
    end = 5
    # Please change the value of loop_num to fix your issue, e.g., 5 times.
    loop_num = 5
    while(initial <= loop_num):
        count_word = count_word_occurences(start, end)
        start += step_constant
        end += step_constant
        initial += 1
    print "\n\nDONE"
```

Please check you loop restriction. In your code, the value of `initial` is initialized as 1 and the loop will keep executing until `initial <= 1` is **not** true. However, it will add 1 to `initial` at the end of first round (`initial += 1`). So the `initial` is 2 now and it is bigger than 1 (`initial <= 1` is not true anymore), so the loop will stop and exit.

Comment: The code in your answer has the same problem as the original.

Comment: @Barmar Got it. Updated, I edited the code and add necessary comment.

Comment: Sorry, I set them the main loop restriction to be 1 so i can debug it faster. But the problem isn't there. It is in the "count_word_occurences" loop.